# Can I edit the snapshots of websites on most visited sites page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, tabs

I saw the previous chain of discussion, but did not find a way to continue the thread - I have found the "Preference" (I have Windows 7), but in that, I did not find clearly what to modify. I did find a section called 'URLs pinned" or something like this, but it did NOT match fully the ones I have.

I have activated the 'profile sync' for Chrome - don't know if it has any effect.

Can you manually edit the icons of the most visited sites, for the new tab page in Chrome?

---

When you open a new tab in Chrome, I get the 'new page' tab, where I selected the 'most popular', so I have 8 icons with the 8 most popular sites I visited; I can also pin any one of those I see on screen, such that they remain 'permanent' there. We are missing one which would point to, say, "hotmail".

So, I was looking for a way to add 'hotmail' to be one of the 8. (and, by the way, we ticked the 'X' on one of those 8, and now it remains grey / shows nothing in it). So, my double-question:

1. How can I add a URL of my choice into one of those 8 spaces?
2. How can I restore usage of the last one?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: When you open a new tab in Chrome, I get the 'new page' tab, where I selected the 'most popular', so I have 8 icons with the 8 most popular sites I visited; I can also pin any one of those I see on screen, such that they remain 'permanent' there. We are missing one which would point to, say, "hotamil". So, I was looking for a way to add 'hotmail' to be one of the 8. (and, by the way, we ticked the 'X' on one of those 8, and now it remains grey / shows nothing in it). So, my double-question: a. how can I add a URL of my choice into one of those 8 spaces? b. how can I restore usage of the last1

Comment: +1 @Ramhound: Please clarify what you don't find clear about the question.

Comment: [Repositioning "Most Visited" List in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/428434/429562#429562) did you read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

When you open the new tab, on the bottom of the page you have a few "buttons": Most Visited and Apps. If it helps, you can drag any link from most visited or bookmarks in the Apps section